# CSS Transitions - Frame rate is reduced when viewing online

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to transition myself from ActionScript 3 to CSS 3D transitions. My animation is as smooth as silk on my Web Server (WAMP) I would guess 60 fps+, but once I FTP it and load it from my Website, the frame rate is noticeably slower and jerky - I'd guess 30 fps.

The page is here:
digiwongadude.com/dwdapps/demos/space_launch/
(click anywhere in the tunnel to trigger the animation)

Don't see any tunnel? The initial screen should look like this:

[image]

It seems hard enough to get these transitions to work across browsers, so I am focusing only on the CHROME BROWSER at the moment.

I am using local [to the site] versions of JQuery and prefixfree.js, so it's not like the page is going off to fetch data elsewhere. Any ideas?

I've noticed similar slow down on a similar CSS example [HERE](http://digiwongadude.com/dwdapps/demos/vortex/)

(hit the go button to start the animation)

If I can just understand WHY this is happening I can deal with it. But the not knowing makes me question whether I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Looks pretty smooth to me. Nothing to do with network I think

Comment: Looks silky smooth to me as well.

Comment: Ok..!? Well that seriously helps guys, thanks! MUST be something on my end.

Comment: It works pretty smooth. You might want to preload all your resources before you actually start the animation. May be that is what is the problem at your end.

Comment: It is smooth here as well. On a side note you should include your code in your question for us to see if you did something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and advice. I found the problem went away and then came back. Knowing it was my end I was able to dig deeper with confidence and located the problem - it was a service in XP using CPU resources (java update). Zach, I'll ensure I use code examples from now on. Thanks all of you! –